# Blackboard messaging using queues

Tags: c#, message-queue, messaging, blackboard

I have an application, where I need to add role-based messaging. The messages are generated ny the application itself, and every message have an starttime (where is show on the client message-window) and an expire-time. Depending on your role, you will see a subset of the messages. Some messages are VERY important, and should be pushed to the client instantly (we are talking milli-seconds - not seconds). Also - when a user log in, he/she should be the current messages for his/her role.

Basically this is a blackboard, where the client see a view of the blackboard (depending on the role). It has to be really fast and reliable, as it will be used in an emergency centre handling calls for ambulances and fire)

Anyone know which technology I should use (application is written in .NET 2.0) or if a product exists, which I could use?

Comment: Has anyone experience using NServiceBus http://www.nservicebus.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [Retlang](http://code.google.com/p/retlang/).

Comment: Retlang could be an alternative, but it seems to be a bit "dead", as latest release were in May 08. I think I'd prefer to base a solution on a technology, which is better supported in the future (if you end up with bugs, you don't know how to solve)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like this is a dream, role for Tibco RV / multicast, if your org has the dough for the license/backend...

If not, have a look at UDP multicast where you server would broadcast all blackboard events, and each client would filter what needs to be displayed.

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Haven't been able to find any licensing or prizing on their web-site - but will quote for one.
UDP multicast could be an option, but I would have to code everything from scratch (including persistence, roles etc). I would like to use some kind of framework, which handles basic functionality.

Comment: Tibco has a lot of modules for this, (persistence, caching, security) but it's a tad expensive. Mostly used by financial institutions.

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

You may try GigaSpaces http://www.gigaspaces.com they provide a pretty mature platform (you may say enterprise ready) for blackboard/messaging systems featuring support of Java and .NET and ability to deal with blackboards/queues/roles on a very fine grade granularity.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the blackboard/messaging features on www.gigaspaces.com - and it seems a bit "big/heavy" for this particular problem

Comment: Yes, it is a big/heavy solution. With respect to the blackboard/messaging feature I think they call it "Space Based Architecture" as it refers to Tuple Spaces en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space